# Selecting typeface from gallery and displaying in next page

Tags: java, android, bundle, typeface

I want to set typeface of fonts of two different types according to whether type face selected from horizontal gridview  which has font types like regular etc another horizontal gridview has neon typeface font.problem is that when i select from neontype face from grid row it displays neon typeface no problem ,but when i pressed back button and selected normal fonttype but the selected font would not display as desired .Here is code

> font_style_ga = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.font_style_ga);

```
    font_style_ga.setAdapter(new FontStyle(this));
```

font_style_ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {

            if (IsNativeAdVisible) {
                return;
            }
            if (position == 0) {
                externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "Creator_Campotype_smcp.otf");
            } else if (position == 1) {
                externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "Gangnam.ttf");
            }
```

Similarty for neontypeface as
neon_font_ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
            if (IsNativeAdVisible) {
                return;
            }
            if(position==0){
                neonFonts=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                        "Neony_font.ttf");
            }


                NeontypeFaceName= neonTypeList[position];
                text_edt.setTextSize(textsize);
                text_edt.setTypeface(neonFonts);



        }
    });


Intent intent = new Intent(TextActivity.this,
                            FirstActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("text", edit_text_str);
                    intent.putExtra("textcolor", textcolor);
                    intent.putExtra("textsize", textsize);
                    intent.putExtra("typeface", typeFaceName);
                    intent.putExtra("neonTypeface",NeontypeFaceName);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

In `firstactivity.java` I am using `getextra` function whether `typeface` or `NeontypeFaceName` is set using if else condition as

```
if (bundleIntent != null) {


        adText.setText(bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("text"));


        if (bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("typeface") == null ) {

            adText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);

        } else {

            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("typeface"));

            adText.setTypeface(typeFace);

        }

        adText.setTextSize(bundleIntent.getExtras().getFloat("textsize"));

        int color = bundleIntent.getExtras().getInt("textcolor");

        if (color == 0) {

            color = Color.BLACK;
        }
        adText.setTextColor(color);


        if(bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("neonTypeface")!=null  ){
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("neonTypeface"));

            adText.setTypeface(typeFace);
            adText.setShadowLayer(11,2,-2,color);


        }else if(bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("typeface")!=null){
            Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    bundleIntent.getExtras().getString("typeface"));

            adText.setTypeface(typeFace);
        }
```

But after pressing back and changing typeface will not get selected typeface. Please help

Comment: Your question title should be a *short* summary of what you're trying to do. The full problem description should go in the body of the question instead. I tried to summarize your title. Feel free to fix it again yourself if you think I missed the point, but please keep it short.

Comment: yes let me describe question